# Строки хранятся в формате Unicode (Python 2.7 )

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Есть код, который  парсит json.

```
with open('test.json','r') as input_file:
stringToParse = json.load(input_file)

testSet = set();
for i in stringToParse:
    testSet.add(i['test'])
```

После `print(TestSet)` выводится unicode вида:

```
u'\u041f\u0438\u0446\u0446\u0430',
u'\u0421\u0443\u0448\u0438',
```

Но при использовании

```
for i in testSet:
    print i
```

Вывод проходит нормально. Есть ли какая либо возможность "хранить" список уже в удобно читаемом виде?

Comment: А можно пример без чтения файла? И желательно его на ideone.

Comment: Почему бы не использовать list? В 2.7 он, вроде, присутствует... https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: @JackWolf в листе в таком же формате хранится

Comment: Может, вам попробовать TestSet.decode(“utf-8”), скорее всего нарушается кодировка